# Export AngularJS srmart table to PDF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

HTML.

```
<button class="btn m-b-xs btn-md btn-primary btn-addon" ng-click="printpdf()"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>Download To Pdf</button>
```

Js.

```js
 $scope.printpdf = function () {
    var mywindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=600');
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Test</title>');

    mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    //var blob = new Blob([document.getElementById('exportable').innerHTML]);
    mywindow.document.write([document.getElementById('exportable2').innerHTML]);
    mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    mywindow.print();
    saveAs(mywindow, "Monthly Summary Report.pdf");
    mywindow.close();
    return true;
}
```

I'm using this function to export to PDF. It's working fine, but when I click the "Download To Pdf" this time opens the print dialog box. I need just to open the save dialog box to pdf.